# Inserting Chinese and Japanese Char in a field with char data type

Tags: mysql, sql

I just want to ask if its possible to insert Chinese and Japanese character in a sql column with char as its data type.?

I am unable to convert it first since the column contain a lot of data and were use by my other application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Just make sure your character set is correctly set in your database. Here are some references to check out.

[MySQL charset](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset.html)
[Unicode reference on CJK](http://unicode.org/faq/han_cjk.html)

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca7d2/1)

Comment: The DB use the below collation:
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

type: char(50)

@Tah Tatsumoto
How can i insert a chinese char to the DB.

as per initial check whenever it try i get ?? in the OrderTxt field

`Insert Into ORDER
(OrderNbr,OrderTxt,UserId,CreateDate,UpdateId,UpdateDate) 
values(0101,'面条',USER1,GETDATE(),USER,GETDATE())`

Comment: Here is the FAQ for MySQL.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-cjk.html the biggest is going to be your MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me in sqlfiddle! (Never tried before and not sure on certain schema's)

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/395a99/1

```
CREATE TABLE ZOOM(
CHINESE CHAR(20),
JAPANESE CHAR(20));

INSERT INTO ZOOM
VALUES('白白白','平仮名');
```

Then

```
SELECT * FROM ZOOM
```

Gives:

```
CHINESE JAPANESE
白白白  平仮名
```

Comment: It depends on server usually.